# Dryer vent duct

Tags: dryer, vent

I bought a new dryer to replace an old one. I am using the old flex duct that was connected to the old (cleaned it first). Can I attached the flex duct right to the back of the new dryer (with clamp)? The duct was connected to the old dryer via a rigid 90 degree elbow rather than direct, so am not sure if that’s how it’s supposed to be done?

The reason I ask is because they had the flex duct clamped to the elbow, but the elbow just slid on the old dryer (no clamps), which I didn’t like.

Comment: The old flex duct: is it more like plastic/ Saran Wrap or more like thick tinfoil?

Answer (score 2):

Usually flex (with clamps at both ends) is used to connect dryer to outlet to allow flexibility of moving the dryer around while connected. Shouldn't be any need for rigid pipe, but if used for any reason then joints should be screwed or taped together.